# app is slow with images in android

Tags: android, android-image

I am doing a app on images to show them in GridView, i am fetching 20 images from server. Resolution of the each image is 720*540.I used  JSON parsing to fetch url and used below code to convert into Bitmap in order to set images.

```
public static Bitmap loadImageFromUrl(String url) {
    InputStream inputStream;Bitmap b;
    try {
        inputStream = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        BitmapFactory.Options bpo=  new BitmapFactory.Options();
        if(bpo.outWidth>500) {
            bpo.inSampleSize=8;
            b=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null,bpo );
        } else {
            bpo.inSampleSize=2;
            b=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null,bpo );
        }
        return  b;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

my app is working fine but it is taking too much time to load the images. So that my app became slow.  Should i decrease the resolution of images?

how to come out of the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are doing a grid view to load 20 images of such resolution, I would suggest the following:

1. Definitely reduce the size of the images. Unless you are targeting a tablet, you will be fine as most smartphones cannot achieve that resolution with 20 images.
2. Cache images if you can.
3. Download the images on a different thread. Store a HashMap would make it easy for you, just put all the imageviews with the image file names or other form of IDs as keys. send message to your Handler when images are downloaded and update the view after it's decoded. You can retrieve your views directly. Just remember to check if they are still in the window. This way the images will show up one after another quickly. I don't think multithreading the images will help, just make sure to use another thread to "push the images" and the main UI thread updates. User experience will be greatly improved then.

Hope this helps.

---some implementations, I don't have the complete code with me right now---

Have a data structure to match the views with data that comes in. very handy here.

```
private HashMap<String,ImageView> pictures;
```

When you get the list of image urls, iterate through them:

```
 pictures.put(id,view);
        try{
            FileInputStream in = openFileInput(id);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, null);
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch(Exception e){
            new Thread(new PictureGetter(this,mHandler,id)).start();
        }
```

(Here the picture getter will simply fetch the image if it is not cached already and cache it)

Code to update the image view:

```
 if(id!=null){
        ImageView iv = pictures.get(id);
        if(iv!=null){
            try{
                FileInputStream in = openFileInput(id);
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, null);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
```

Comment: i used asynchronous way to fetch images.

Comment: If you are showing that many images, can't you show thumbnails on the grid view? After you fetch all of those, you start fetching some of the original resolution in the background so if they click on it it will be fetched.

Comment: yes this idea is good, is it possible to convert images into thumbnails through program

Comment: yea. depending on which image type you are working with there are different image optimization and resizing program. PS will be suffice for resizing and average optimization.

Comment: can you please give some idea or link to convert into thumbnails

Comment: through programmatically i want

Comment: Titus, if you were to programmatically create the thumbnails, you would still have to retrieve the large images from the server and it would not help your cause. What Edison means is that you create the thumbnails yourself with the image editor of your choice, and store them on the server next to your hi-res images. That way you can download the thumbnails much quicker and show those to the user while you fetch the hi-res images in the background.

Comment: thank you bram, but when i am getting outofmemoryerror sometimes

Comment: If you use BitmapInfo with the right sizes and reuse bitmaps, you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

[Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Solution is instead of using bitmap to load image directly use a awesome Library called Picasso its just super fast i know you really love this you can do this like this

Add picasso jar file to your project (Download picasso jar file here) Use picasso to load the Image like this

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(title)).centerCrop()
    .resize(150, 150).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(image);
```

where title is the image path which you want to load. Crop,resize, error are optional.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that most of the loading time is because of the large amount of images combined with the size of the images.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Resize the images, or lower the quality of the images so that the filesize is below 75kb or so.
2. Use multi-threading to retrieve multiple images at once. This might not help if the user's connection is really slow, but if you combine this with a small enough filesize it might just help out enough. You might want to determine what the current bandwidth of the device is and base the number of threads you run on that.

For instance: 20 images of 75KB each and an available connection of 200 KB/s = 3 or 4 concurrent threads.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for reply, can you tell me how to use 2nd option in your answer please

Comment: i used asynchronous way to fetch all the images

Comment: @Titus if you have problems with applying the idea Bram gave you create another question and show us the code you have done and where your problems are we can only help you out if you have a specific problem. Stackoverflow will not simply give you alle the code you need for copy and pasting.

Comment: Firing multiple network events are bad in a mobile environment with large files. TCP protocol will hunt all of your threads down when congestion starts.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem in my android app. When you decode a bitmap from a big sized image and set as imageBitmap to an image view probably your application will slow and after a few try you'll get an "out of memory exception"

Two of the possible ways you can try to handle this problem:
1- Reduce bitmap size when you decode from file
2- Use an image library.

I prefered second way and used Universal Image Loader. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
String url = "file://" + your_file_path
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, ivPicture, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class clothImageLoader {

// the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with
// something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
// public static HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache = new HashMap<String,
// Bitmap>();

private static File cacheDir;

public clothImageLoader(Context context) {
    // Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect
    // the UI performance
    photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);

    // Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        // cacheDir=new
        // File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        cacheDir = new File(ConstValue.MY_ClothBitmap_DIR);
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.icon;

public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
    if (ConstValue.ClothRoomcache.containsKey(url))
        imageView.setImageBitmap(ConstValue.ClothRoomcache.get(url));
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
    // This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be
    // some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them.
    photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
    }

    // start thread if it's not started yet
    if (photoLoaderThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
        photoLoaderThread.start();
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    // I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the
    // demo.
    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);

    // from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        /*
         * InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream(); OutputStream os = new
         * FileOutputStream(f); Utils.CopyStream(is, os); os.close();
         */
        URL url1 = new URL(url);
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = url1.openConnection();

        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        // FlushedInputStream a = new FlushedInputStream(is);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = ConstValue.bmpSize;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale++;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

PhotosQueue photosQueue = new PhotosQueue();

public void stopThread() {
    photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
}

// stores list of photos to download
class PhotosQueue {
    private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad = new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

    // removes all instances of this ImageView
    public void Clean(ImageView image) {
        for (int j = 0; j < photosToLoad.size();) {
            if (photosToLoad.get(j).imageView == image)
                photosToLoad.remove(j);
            else
                ++j;
        }
    }
}

class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                // thread waits until there are any images to load in the
                // queue
                if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() == 0)
                    synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                        photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                    }
                if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() != 0) {
                    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                    synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                        photoToLoad = photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();

                        // photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.get(0);
                        // photosQueue.photosToLoad.remove(photoToLoad);
                    }
                    Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                    ConstValue.ClothRoomcache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                    if (((String) photoToLoad.imageView.getTag()).equals(photoToLoad.url)) {
                        BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                        Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                    }
                }
                if (Thread.interrupted())
                    break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // allow thread to exit
        }
    }
}

PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread = new PhotosLoader();

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView imageView;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i) {
        bitmap = b;
        imageView = i;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public static void clearCache() {
    // clear memory cache
    ConstValue.ClothRoomcache.clear();

    // clear SD cache
    File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
    for (File f : files)
        f.delete();
}

public class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int a = read();
                if (a < 0) {
                    break; // we reached EOF
                } else {
                    bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                }
            }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}

}
```

when you call the method ,in the gridView getView method:

```
holder.image.setTag(ChoseInfo.get(position).getLink());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(ChoseInfo.get(position).getLink(), activity, holder.image);
```

> ChoseInfo.get(position).getLink())

Here `getLink()` is internet link.

Comment: what is ConstValue class. pls share