# One image works fine and other one slow code so much

Tags: java, android

So I am doing small game in android studio - java. And I was using 400x400 .png image as a ship. It worked well.

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.playermove),(int)(length),(int)(height),false);
```

I am using `drawBitmap` to draw image on screen.

Now I want to use different ship. Only thing that I changed is that instead of this image I use another one that is 150x150 also .png and game becomes so laggy and sloopy.
Length and Height are 1/10 size of the screen. I have 8 ship pictures with similair dimensions and every one make game sloppy.
Any idea why those pictures make everything sloppy and first one doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing that on the UI thread. You shouldn't!

Comment: Well, I have 2 threads, in one I scale image, in other I draw. If you have half of hour of spare time, I have few thread questions about threads in Android (for my project) that I can't find on internet, but can't  ask them here because I would need to send whole project.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not to scale `Bitmap` dynamically, as bitmap scaling is bit expensive, and if you are doing that in `onDraw()` which would be triggered every ~17ms, doing redundant/expensive work is bad. I'd suggest you to preprocess the image and keep a scaled version of it and just use it to draw  every time.

Answer (score 0):

you are not optimizing your images and this is a background work. try to do this in background.

also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991865/app-is-slow-with-images-in-android) may help you.